# How can I change the name of the _nuxt folder?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Hello I've got an issue with a Nuxt.js app that I can't seem to resolve. What I want to do is to change the name of the generated `_nuxt` folder with some other name. So far I've updated the `nuxt.config.js` and added this snippet:

`build: {
    publicPath: '/new-folder'
  },`

as far as I understand this publicPath variable expects a CDN link so probably this is not the correct way of changing the default `_nuxt` folder name.

I have also tried adding the `buildDir: 'new-folder` but when I run the build command it doesn't show up in the project. No matter what changes I added in the nuxt.config file when I deployed it on heroku all the assets where still in the `_nuxt` folder which causes issues to my project. Am I not seeing something am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you using universal or spa mode?

Answer (score 8):

Since the default answer in nuxt JS Documentation is `/_nuxt/`. The correct answer should be `/yourCustomName/` - be ware that you need two forward slash.

In **nuxt.config.js**

```js
build: {
  publicPath: '/customName/'
}
```

Comment: this is the same I have answered, months before, and 1 negative vote...

Answer (score 2):

t's simple, just change in build the `publicPath`.
buildDir is to change the folder for development, where the files will be when coding

nuxt.config.js:

```js
build: {
    publicPath: 'new-folder/',
},
```

in my case, my publicPath is `leo/`
[image]

you can check more about it here:
https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/how-to-set-custom-configuration-for-nuxt-js-generate-task-5055e53c2da5

Answer (score 0):

For Nuxt3, at `nuxt.config.ts`, try:

```
    app: {
        buildAssetsDir: 'folder-here',
    },
```